# JComboBox not showing the elements

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am developing the Exam Registration System with MVC in java.I can add comboBox into big JPanel.However,when I push the JComboBox button , there is no element in the combobox.I can not solve this. ComboBox addition to my view is here ;

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(425, 494, 117, 39);
    adminPanel.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setVisible(true);

    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setBounds(0, 0, 117, 39);
    panel.add(comboBox);
```

and ı try to add exams in here ;

```
        admin_view.getComboBox().setVisible(true);
        String s = "Exam1";
        admin_view.getComboBox().addItem(s);
```

How can I show the elements into JComboBox. No action , no other things I just want to show elements.

Comment: 1) Stop using a null layout!!! This has already been suggestion in a previous posting. 2) Start accepting answers when people answer your questions. 3) Post a proper `SSCCE` when you post a question. You have also been asked to do this in another question. There is no way we can answer the question based on the current information given.

Answer (score -1):

```
admin_view.getComboBox().setVisible(true);
String s = "Exam1";
admin_view.getComboBox().addItem(s);
```

The problem is; you try to add an element to an already visible object. So if you add an element, you have to refresh the component/panel to see updated version of that component/panel. And if the elements don't have to be added dynamically, just add those elements before you make that combobox visible.

Comment: -1,  `So if you add an element, you have to refresh the component/panel to see updated version of that component/panel`, yes, if you add a new component to a visible GUI then you need to revalidate() and repaint() the panel. However, when you update the `Model` of a visible component, the model will notify the `View` so the view can repaint itself automatically.